# Angular 4 Observable on Array in Service

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs, observable

I have an interface that implements an array in a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

interface Artwork {

    artTitle: string;
    slideUrl?: string;
}


let Artwks: Artwork [] = [];

Artwks.push({
    artTitle: "'Surprising Breakfast Ideas'",
    slideUrl: './assets/SBI_Slide_1.jpg', 

});

Artwks.push({
    artTitle: "'Eagle'",
    slideUrl: './assets/Eagle_Slide_2.jpg', 
});

Artwks.push({
    artTitle: "'Knot'",
    slideUrl: './assets/Knot_Slide_3.jpg', 
});

@Injectable()


export class ImageServiceService {

  Artwks = Artwks;
  i: number = 0;

    getIndex() {
      return this.i ;
    }

    getSlide() {
        return this.Artwks[this.i].slideUrl;
    }

    getPrev() {
        this.i = this.i===0 ? 0 : this.i - 1;
        this.getTitle();
        console.log(this.getTitle());
        this.getSlide();
    }

    getNext() {
        this.i = this.i===this.Artwks.length ? this.i : this.i + 1;
        this.getTitle();
        console.log(this.getTitle());
        this.getSlide();
    }

    getTitle(): Observable<Artwork.artTitle>  {
        return this.Artwks[this.i].artTitle;
    }



}
```

I want a component that displays the title of the array when getNext() or getPrev() is called on the service, but I don't know how to set up my observable so it updates the value of artTitle every time it changes?

I get error "'Artwork' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a string from `getTitle()` so your type should be `string`.

```
getTitle(): string { //.etc
```

EDIT:

If you want to use an observable, you need to *make* an observable and return it somewhere. I'm not sure how to do this without knowing how your class is used, but the basic idea looks like this:

Create and subject observable:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class ImageServiceService {
    public artworks:Subject<Artwork> = new Subject(); 

    private index: number = 0

    getArt(){
      this.artworks.next(this.Artwks[this.index])
      this.index++
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Then in your component you can subscribe to the observable:

```
  constructor(private imageService: ImageServiceService){
    this.artworks = imageService.artworks
    this.artworks.subscribe(v => // do something with it)

    // artworks should update with the subject calls next()
  }
```

Comment: That's what I feared! I guess what I'm asking is how do I make the artTitle string into an Observable so I can observe it from a component that is unrelated to the component calling the getNext and getPrev functions?

Comment: You need to make an observable and push the values into it with `next()`. See edit for the rough outline.